# previous and next state info displayed in console with redux-persist

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have integrated redux-persist as below.

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
}
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)

While loading the application, its printing prev state and next state information in command prompt console.  How to avoid displaying this info ?

```
prev state {

    user: {
      userId: '',
      employeename: '',

    },
    productItem: {
      additionalDetails: { data: [], isLoading: false },
    },
    _persist: { version: -1, rehydrated: false }
  }
   action     {
    type: 'persist/REHYDRATE',
    payload: undefined,
    err: undefined,
    key: 'root'
  }
```

Comment: Where is this console.log coming from? In Chrome devtools there is usually a link to the exact line of code that logs it.

Comment: I haven't added any console.log. This info is getting printed only in command prompt where i started from server. But, in chrome console, nothing is display.

Comment: Just a guess here but does `const persistConfig = { key: 'root', storage, debug:false}` change anything?

Comment: Already tried this.  But no luck

Comment: If you are using `redux-logger` middleware remove it.. then they won't appear anymore

Comment: Thanks. After removing middleware logger, it got disappeared.

Comment: But, I am seeing one weird warning in console.                                                      
       
redux-persist failed to create sync storage. falling back to noop storage